# Using FOR loop in Psexec

Tags: loops, batch-file, for-loop, psexec

I'm trying to use remotely a for loop with a psexec but I can't do it. Also I neet to use it with a variable (date)

I'm trying something like that

```
psexec -u user -p password \\computer cmd /c FOR /R C:\FOLDER1\%date%\ %i in (*.txt) do C:\FOLDER2\MyTool.exe %i
```

I'm tried to put it in many ways but it didn't work. Sometimes it return unexpected error or something like \FOLDER1\%date%\ was not expected in this moment.

If I connect to the remote computer with psexec and after that I write the next sentence it works.

```
FOR /R C:\FOLDER1\%date%\ %i in (*.txt) do C:\FOLDER2\MyTool.exe %i
```

But I need to use inside my batch, not outside.

What is wrong? What can I do?

Comment: Double your percents when used in a batch file: `%i` becomes `%%i`

Comment: There was the mistake. The batch works perfectly with %%i. Thank you!!!!